# How can I update data using NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

i want to update result prediction to database mysql, but data cannot save at database.

```
const periode = _.get(row, "periode", new Date());
const prediction =
          b0 +
          b1 * Number.parseFloat(_.get(row, "x1", 0)) +
          b2 * Number.parseFloat(_.get(row, "x2", 0));

        const sql = `UPDATE performance SET prediction_result="${prediction}" WHERE periode="${periode}"`;

        db.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
              console.error('An error occurred while executing the query')
              throw error
            }
          })
```

i am getting error like this:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
ReferenceError: connection is not defined
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show where you are defining `connection` variable ?

Comment: connection defining on index.js but i make that code in another file.js

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this in your code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db= mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: Debug it: first console.log sql and try it directly